# Como incluir um botão em html a partir de um resultado em php

Tags: php

REFORMULADO A PERGUNTA!

Gostaria da ajuda dos senhores, de como criar um botão, para copiar o resultado da função `echo` do PHP. Por exemplo:

Código em PHP

```
echo "Nome: " . $row_usuario['nome'] . "<br>";
```

Apareça isso para o usuário:

```
Nome: siclano da silva
```

Como poderia criar esse botão em HTML (podendo ser de outra forma) para copiar o resultado da saída da função `echo` da tela do navegador, onde esse copiar será para área de transferência, como se fosse <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> / <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>?

melhorando a minha pergunta, esse aqui é código em questão.

```
            <label>Nome: </label>
            <input type="text" name="nome" placeholder="Digite aqui"><br><br>
            
            <input name="SendPesqUser" type="submit" value="Pesquisar">
        </center>
        </form><br><br>
        
        <form>
        
        <center>
        <div>
        <input type="button" value="cadastra novo solicitante de crédito consignado" onClick="Nova()">
        </div>
        <div>
        <input type="button" value="Consultar crédito" onClick="Novo2()">
        </div>
        <div>
        <input type="button" value="Página Inicial" onClick="NovoInicial()">
        </div>
        </center>
        </form> 
        
        
        <?php
        $SendPesqUser = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'SendPesqUser', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        if($SendPesqUser){
            $nome = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'nome', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
            $result_usuario = "SELECT * FROM fornecedores WHERE nome LIKE '%$nome%'";
            $resultado_usuario = mysqli_query($con, $result_usuario);
            while ($row_usuario = $resultado_usuario->fetch_assoc()) {
                
                
                echo "Nome: " . $row_usuario['nome'] . "<br>";
                echo "Endereço: " . $row_usuario['endereco'] . "<br>";
                echo "Cep: " . $row_usuario['cep'] . "<br>";
                echo "E-mail: " . $row_usuario['email'] . "<br>";
                echo "Celular: " . $row_usuario['celular'] . "<br>";
                echo "Valor do crédito: " . $row_usuario['valor'] . "<br>";
                echo "Id: " . $row_usuario['id'] . "<br>";
                
                
                echo "<a href='edit_usuario.php?id=" . $row_usuario['id'] . "'>Editar</a><br>";
                echo "<a href='proc_apagar_usuario.php?id=" . $row_usuario['id'] . "'>Apagar</a><br><hr>";
            }
        }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

https://ibb.co/h7b7TRb

O resultado seria isso como conforme a imagem do link acima, a pessoa iria fazer uma pesquisa pelo banco de dados, ai o resultado que aparecera na tela, gostaria que fosse copiado via clipboard por um botão, pois a intenção é a pessoa copiar esse dados e depois lança em mensagem no whatsapp.

obs: sou iniciante no ramo de programação, peço desculpa por não saber ainda como me expressar de uma forma adequada com as minhas dúvidas, agradeço profundamente a ajuda do senhores.

meu nível de conhecimento é de muito esforço em querer aprender e muitas coisas posso ainda não entender.

Comment: Em resumo, você quer que quando clique num botão, execute um código PHP e o retorno desse código PHP vá para a área de transferência do usuário? Sua pergunta ficou um tanto confusa

Comment: Pelo que entendi ele quer que ao clicar em um botão execute um código em javascript que copie o conteúdo de algum elemento html para área de transferência.

Answer (score 0):

Boa noite Claudio,
Neste caso você precisa colocar dentro de um while e dentro colocar alguma condicional, assim sempre que a condicional for atendida o botão aparecera. Ex:

$query = "SELECT * FROM TABLE_1 WHERE USER =".$user."";
$row =($query,$db)//query e conexão com o banco de dados
while($row['user'] == ".$id."){
echo"
Vê usuario//Vê um modal bootstap
//Poe um modal e faz o select dentro.
";
}

}

Comment: eu refiz a pergunta. incluindo mais elementos, agradeço pelo seu comentário.

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que entendi, você deseja copiar um elemento html para área de transferência ao executar a ação de clique.
Se sua aplicação lida com browsers modernos, esses browsers possuem uma nova api que possui compatibilidade com a api `clipboard`.

Para executar esta ação de uma maneira que ela possua compatibilidade com a maioria dos browsers o ideal seria que seja feita uma implementação que possua compatibilidade com novos browsers e antigos.

Supondo que temos a tag html label com `id='meuelemento'` e o conteúdo `saída` e desejamos copiar o texto `saída` para área de transferência.

```
<label id="meuelemento">saida</label>
<button type="button" onclick="copyToClipboardAction()">Area transferência</button>


<script>
  function copyToClipboardAction() {
    const textoCopiar = document.getElementById("meuelemento")
    const txtToCopy = navigator.clipboard.writeText(textoCopiar.textContent)
}
</script>
```

Neste caso o valor `saida`, será copiado para a área de transferência.

Repare que utilizando este fluxo se o seu browser não possui implementação da api do clipboard (browsers antigos) ocorrerá um erro.

Então a maneira ideal de tratar isso é fazer um `try...catch` e se ocorrer um erro devemos fazer um tratamento especial para manipular este caso.

Este fluxo está representado no catch:

1. Insere um elemento input novo no html
2. Setamos um id a este elemento para que ele possa ser encontrado no html.
3. pegamos este elemento pelo id adicionado no passo anterior.
4. adicionamos este elemento ao html atual
5. inserimos o valor a ser copiado ao elemento html inserido
6. inserimos o foco no elemento input html a ser inserido
7. selecionamos o `text()` do input adicionar.
8. executamos a função execCommand('copy'), que é o comando que copia valores para área de transferência.
9. removemos o elemento que inserimos, para deixar o html de acordo com quando iniciamos a modificação do html.

Segue o código:

```
<script>
function copyToClipboardAction() {
  const textoCopiar = document.getElementById("meuelemento")
  try {
    const txtToCopy = navigator.clipboard.writeText(textoCopiar.textContent)
  } catch (error) {
     const input = document.createElement('entradainput')
     input.setAttribute('id', 'elementoclipboard')
     const fakeReadOnlyElement = document.getElementById("meuelemento")
     const divpai = fakeReadOnlyElement.parentNode
     divpai.insertBefore(input, fakeReadOnlyElement)
     input.value = textToCopy
     input.focus()
     input.select()
     document.execCommand('copy')
     const elementoRemover = document.getElementById('entradainput')
     elementoRemover.remove()
  }
}
</script>
```

Você pode validar que este fluxo foi bem sucedido se após implementar estas mudanças você apertar <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> o conteúdo da variável `meuelemento` deve estar na área de transferência.

Comment: eu refiz a pergunta. incluindo mais elementos, gostaria de ver a possibilidade de ser analisado novamente.

Comment: realmente funcionou o script, mas agora meu desafio é, copiar, as informações que são mostrada no ECHO. mandei um link com a imagem, onde quando pesquiso um nome X no banco de dados, abaixo retorna o que tem, ex: na busca apareceu o id 61 (alem do nome, etc, e 69), gostaria de fazer agora esse script copiar esses dados.

Comment: Desculpa, não entendo de php. não sei dizer.